# Power supply for 1.7A stepper motors

Tags: arduino, power-supply, stepper-motor

I am an amateur making my own CNC machine.  This involves manufacturing or buying all component parts as appropriate. I am trying to understand what power supply I will have to provide to operate the stepper motors that I intend to use. Even though I will buy a suitable power supply if possible, I still need to design the system to suit the current required and the appropriate voltage to make the system operate properly but safely.
I'm told that 'just applying Ohms law' will not tell me the voltage I need but I don't understand how to work out what is needed.

I will have 3 stepper motors rated at 1.7A maximum each, with 1.5 Ohm coils. The driver ICs are [**A4988**](https://www.pololu.com/file/download/a4988_DMOS_microstepping_driver_with_translator.pdf?file_id=0J450) rated at 35V, 2A max.

What would be the optimal power supply to use with 3 of [**these stepper motors**](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/CE-certification-1pcs-4-lead-Nema17-Stepper-Motor-42-motor-Nema-17-motor-42BYGH-1-7A/32377416566.html?spm=2114.01020208.3.137.PeSQSn&ws_ab_test=searchweb201556_0,searchweb201602_5_10057_10056_10065_10068_10055_10054_10069_10059_10058_418_10073_10017_10070_10060_10061_10052_10062_10053_10050_10051,searchweb201603_7&btsid=d548654f-3f77-4454-b1a2-194619cf74fb) and 3 A4988 drivers + [GRBL stepper motor driver card](http://dank.bengler.no/-/bulletin/show/634222_one-stop-arduino-shield-for-grbl)

I am confused because the motors don't mention Voltage anywhere in their datasheet.

---

CNC Shield V3.0 features: 
Latest CNC Shield Version 3.0

GRBL 0.8c compatible. (Open source firmware that runs on an Arduino UNO that turns G-code commands into stepper signals)

4-Axis support (X, Y, Z , A-Can duplicate X,Y,Z or do a full 4th axis with custom firmware using pins D12 and D13)

2 x End stops for each axis (6 in total)

Spindle enable and direction

Coolant enable

Uses removable Pololu A4988 compatible stepper drivers. (A4988, DRV8825 and others)

Jumpers to set the Micro-Stepping for the stepper drivers. (Some drivers like the DRV8825 can do up to 1/32 micro-stepping )

Compact design.

Stepper Motors can be connected with 4 pin molex connectors or soldered in place.

Runs on 12-36V DC. (At the moment only the Pololu DRV8825 drivers can handle up to 36V so please consider the operation voltage when powering the board.)

[**aliexpress link for the shield**](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-shipping-cnc-shield-v3-engraving-machine-3D-Printer-4pcs-A4988-driver-expansion-board-for-Arduino/32655526846.html?spm=2114.10010108.1000014.7.B4SyFw&scm=1007.13338.47797.0&pvid=08ab0f94-3a74-4462-8c80-fcbd3dc375d7&tpp=1)

Comment: ... Have you considered asking *them*?

Comment: The coil resistance is 1.7ohm, coil current is 1.5A. The motor is made for 2.5V supplies. I don't, in any way want to deter you from your project, but please start with a basic electronics book. You will save yourself WORLDS of trouble. I've included two free books to start with.
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Practical_Electronics
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Electronics

Comment: @pgvoorhees -- you can (should) use higher voltage supplies with stepper motors to achieve proper performance, typically 12~24V with these small hobby ones -- not 2.5V. A stepper driver takes care of current limiting.

Comment: @WesleyLee No doubt. It is the specified voltage.  I misspoke,  Should have said the motor is made for a 2.5V drop across the coil.

Comment: @WesleyLee  Is there a risk of burning something with too high Voltage ? Also how many amps would be enough for all 3 to operate at max simultaneously. All in all what would be the perfect supply to buy. I have a 20 volt 3 amps supply laying around. Would it do the motors justice or it would bottleneck the whole system ?

Comment: Links to A4988 and grbl "interface".

Comment: The GRBL interface card I linked to and gave specs for may well not be your one - if not I suggest you edit to suit. Also, if they use the TI DRV8811 it seems to be rated at 2.5A - probably OK, but ... .

Comment: @RussellMcMahon https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-shipping-Keyestudio-3D-CNC-kit-for-arduino-CNC-Shield-V3-UNO-R3-4pcs-A4988/32664138636.html?spm=2114.01020208.3.11.dU3lGU&ws_ab_test=searchweb201556_0,searchweb201602_5_10057_10056_10065_10068_10055_10054_10069_10059_10058_418_10073_10017_10070_10060_10061_10052_10062_10053_10050_10051,searchweb201603_7&btsid=b336e696-18ef-41c4-b431-1b14dbe9aebf Here is the one I plan to buy.

Comment: @begginer3 Edit answer for actual controiller. | Note that A4988 is 2A peak driver. See [here](https://www.pololu.com/file/download/a4988_DMOS_microstepping_driver_with_translator.pdf?file_id=0J450) & [here](http://www.allegromicro.com/en/Products/Motor-Driver-And-Interface-ICs/Bipolar-Stepper-Motor-Drivers/A4988.aspx) & [here](http://www.robotshop.com/media/files/PDF/datasheet-1182.pdf)   & [**aaaaaaaagh**](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=a4988+datasheet&num=100&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9m8jch6PPAhUKlZQKHXlXDpEQsAQIOw&biw=1680&bih=871)

Comment: FYI [here](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Sparkfun%20PDFs/BigEasyDriverHookupGuide_Web.pdf) & [here](http://www.schmalzhaus.com/BigEasyDriver/BigEasyDriver_UserManal.pdf) & [whatever ... :-}](https://www.google.co.nz/search?num=100&site=&source=hp&q=a4988+datasheet&oq=a4988&gs_l=hp.1.2.0i67k1l4j0j0i20k1l2j0i67k1j0l2.2586.4583.0.8985.6.6.0.0.0.0.312.1088.2-2j2.4.0....0...1c.1.64.hp..2.3.787.0..35i39k1.BCb7-c5Mb9I)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I did some editing. Better now ? Also, i didnt know that the voltage limit was being set by the A4988 drivers (so its <35V). Now i know.

Comment: Current needed for certainty that all 3 motors can run at full speed simultaneously = 3 x Imax = 3 x 1.5A = 4.5A. Chances are that a lower current supply will be adequate most of the time. A higher current supply is Ok - just unneeded. Controller IC work on 8-35 VDC. Avoid low end as performance improves with voltage. Avoid absolute top end as having some headroom is wise. I have no specific experience in this area but I'd guesstimate 20-30V range is OK and other CNC people would know what worked well.  Higher voltage works bettwer as contrioller can apply higher voltage to ramp current up ...

Comment: ... rapidly and then throttle back to maintain desired current. Effectively time constant = L/R (inductance / resistance) and higher voltage makes source look more like a high impedance current source so time constant goes down.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I can not find 24V 6A anywhere.. just 24V 5A. Should i just go for the 5 or will I end up wasting my money and buying a second stronger one ?

Comment: @begginer3 The 5A supply is liable to work well enough. | 5A ~= 6A as far as power supply specs go :-). ie it MAY really cut off at 5A but will usually sag somwhat in voltage and supply slightly more. Also, as noted in various comments the worst case continous load = 3 x 1.7A but presumably you will slecom have all 2 axis driving at max speed simultaneously. | Higher current supply may help "stiffness" under high loads but seems unlikely to be essential.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I ended up buying a 5amp 24V supply. But i havent tested it yet.

Answer (score 4):

Voltage is not mentioned in the motor datasheet because proper driving of stepper motors is done by controlling the current through their windings, not their voltage.

What is typically done is that you have a supply that must provide a voltage way higher than what is theoretically required (here 1.7Ohm * 1.5A = 2.55V), and you have a stepper driver that will chop this voltage before providing them to the windings, to ensure that the rated current (1.5A) is never exceeded. That will lead to a voltage across the windings that has a high peak at the beginning, and then decays to finally reach the steady state voltage. This way of driving the stepper will ensure best speed and torque performances.

In short: You can choose the voltage you want (higher is supposed to be better because it will drive the motors more easily, but stay within the specifications of the drivers you choose). Just ensure that the supply will be able to supply the peak current required a per the motor specifications.

Comment: Thank you. So it has to be lower than 35 V (and has to have good cooling in high volts I assume). But how many amps would be enough for all 3 to operate at max simultaneously. Is it a simple addition ? So 1.7+1.7+1.7= Around 5-6 amps. Or it works differently ? Would a 3 amp 20V supply bottleneck the system immensely ?

Comment: @begginer3 Current needs add so 5.1A at full cry. 20V OK as long as controller allows.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Would it be better to have 5 or 6 Amps ? Can a higher amperage damage something? Cause i doubt i will find exactly 5,1 amps.

Comment: @beginner If you want to be on the safe side, with belts and suspenders, you do the simple addition. This way, you ensure nothing can ever be overloaded, whatever the usage you make of it. Now, it could be enough to use a 20V 3A, depending on the usage. Because the full 1.7A at 20V for a winding will only be used for a short time, before the motor reaches steady state. After that, the driver will chop the voltage at a much lower rate (closer to the theoretical average of 2.5V, leading to an average current of ~220mA). But it depends on many factors: the motor speed, their loads, etc...

Comment: @beginner If I were you, I wouldn't take risks and use a supply that can provide the whole 5.1A. You can use a supply that is able to provide more (like 6A), no problem, it will just cost more, but it won't damage anything. The supply can be damaged if it's not able to provide enough, but nothing can be damaged if it is able to provide more.

Comment: @begginer3 What he said, deep-ending on load BUT it's OK for psu to have higher CURRENT rating - max voltage rating is set by driver spec.

Comment: @dim i can not find 24V 6A anywhere.. just 24V 5A. Should i just go for the 5 or will I end up wasting my money and buying a second stronger one ?

Comment: @beginner. You can go with the 5A. Anyway, you should be able to set the current limit to the value you want for each motor on the driver board. So if you want to be super safe, just set the limit to a bit less than 1.7A.